# Functions returning functions

Tags: python

The following code snippet which I came across, has output as `6,6,6,6`

```
def multipliers():
    return [lambda x : i * x for i in range(4)]

print([m(2) for m in multipliers()])
```

I don't understand why the output is `6,6,6,6` instead of `0,2,4,6` ?

Can anyone please help me understand the internals of the above code as I am very new to Python.
Thanks.

Comment: While the duplicate is accurate, I'm sure there is a better duplicate - will update when I find it, you can also read the documentation: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: Also: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

Comment: @AChampion we have a few clear canonicals for this problem now (depending on how the question is phrased).